# iOS - GCD and __strong reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks

I have this code and what I am trying to do is to keep self alive in the block that it will be executed on the main thread. The result is kind of random and sometimes print null.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.proArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    GCDVC2* __weak weakSelf = self;

    self.postGCDBlock = ^{

        GCDVC2* __strong strongSelf2 = weakSelf;

        [strongSelf2.proArray removeObject:@"3"];
        NSLog(@"%@",strongSelf2.proArray);
        [strongSelf2.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    };

    self.addObjectsBlock = ^{

        GCDVC2* __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;

        [strongSelf.proArray addObject:@"2"];
        [strongSelf.proArray addObject:@"3"];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),strongSelf.postGCDBlock);
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), self.addObjectsBlock);

}
```

This code works fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.proArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    GCDVC2* __weak weakSelf = self;


    //self.postGCDBlock = ;

    self.addObjectsBlock = ^{

        GCDVC2* __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;

        [strongSelf.proArray addObject:@"2"];
        [strongSelf.proArray addObject:@"3"];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];

         GCDVC2* __weak weakSelf2 = strongSelf;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

            GCDVC2* __strong strongSelf = weakSelf2;

            [strongSelf.proArray removeObject:@"3"];
            NSLog(@"%@",strongSelf.proArray);
            [strongSelf.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), self.addObjectsBlock);

}
```

Is there any way to convert the second piece of code to work with the structure of the first piece of code? I tried a lot of variations but it's always random. Can I somehow assure that the self.postGCDBlock won't have self to nil?

Update:
Property declaration:

```
typedef void(^CustomBlock)(void);

@interface GCDVC2 ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *proArray;
@property (nonatomic, copy) CustomBlock addObjectsBlock;
@property (nonatomic, copy) CustomBlock postGCDBlock;
@end
```

Comment: How does the property declaration look like in the view controller?

Comment: Updated the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue lies with this line (I cannot reproduce the failure case with this code):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),strongSelf.postGCDBlock);
```

At this point in your `addObjectsBlock`, `strongSelf` is holding a reference to `self`, but that ends when you leave the scope of that block. `dispatch_async` will copy the `postGCDBlock`, but that block is not holding a strong reference to `self`.

To get `dispatch_async` to hold a strong reference to `self`, you would want to do something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    strongSelf.postGCDBlock();
});
```

Wrapping `strongSelf` in the block will cause `dispatch_async` to retain `strongSelf` (and thereby `self`) long enough for it to call `postGCDBlock`.

Comment: That solved the issue. I thought that by using `strongSelf.postGCDBlock` as  parameter it would retain the strongSelf